Automate SVG Graph using Selenium Java
Website link: https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/india-population/
Actually I want to fetch the values as I hover on line of graph and capture the data for every year. The years is from 1951 to 2024, so how to do it
I am trying with x and y coordinator of the svg rect , and using actions class of selenium and used moveToELement(), and its not working, I dont know why
My Code
package selenium_concepts.SVGElements;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
public class IndianPopulationSVGElementTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;
    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
        driver.get("https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/india-population/");
    }
    @Test(description = "India Population Graph data test")
    public void svgGraphIndiaPopulation() throws InterruptedException {
        jse = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        WebElement popGraph = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g']"));
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", popGraph);
        String heading = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#maincounter-wrap h1")).getText();
        String totalPopulationIndia = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".maincounter-number span")).getText();
        String indianPopulationBetweenYear = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='chart-header'])[1]")).getText();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println(" -------------- " + heading + " ----------------- ");
        System.out.println("Total Population India: " + totalPopulationIndia);
        System.out.println("Between Years: " + indianPopulationBetweenYear);
        WebElement rectPop = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//*[local-name()='svg'])[1]//*[name()='g']//*[name()='rect'])[1]"));
        Dimension dimension = rectPop.getSize();
        int rectHeight = dimension.getHeight();
        int rectWidth = dimension.getWidth();
        int X = rectPop.getLocation().getX();
        int Y = rectPop.getLocation().getY();
        System.out.println("X: " + X);
        System.out.println("Y: " + Y);
        System.out.println("Dimension: " + dimension);
        System.out.println("Height: " + rectHeight);
        System.out.println("Width: " + rectWidth);
        // height == 260
        // y = (260/2) - 260 = -130
        int getTopLeftY = ((rectPop.getSize().getHeight()) / 2 - rectPop.getSize().getHeight());
        // weight = 520
        // X = (520/2) - 520 == -260
        int getTopLeftX = ((rectPop.getSize().getWidth()) / 2 - rectPop.getSize().getWidth());
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            actions.moveToElement(rectPop, getTopLeftX, getTopLeftY).perform();
        }
        /*

        WebElement popGraphSVG = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='defs' and @id='_ABSTRACT_RENDERER_ID_0']"));
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(popGraphSVG).perform();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        actions.click();

        List<WebElement> tooltipsContents = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g' and @class='google-visualization-tooltip']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='text']"));
        String populationYear = tooltipsContents.getFirst().getText();
        String totalPopulationInYear = tooltipsContents.get(2).getText();

        System.out.println(populationYear + " ----> " + totalPopulationInYear);

        WebElement tracker = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[local-name()='svg']//*[name()='g']//*[name()='circle'])[1]"));

        for (int i = 1; i <10 ; i++) {
            actions
                    .moveToElement(tracker, 0, i)
                    .perform();
        }

         */
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.quit();
    }
}


what's not working?  You should be aware that moveToElement will move to the center of the element.  The 2nd and 3rd arguments are offsets from there.  Ex: element, -1, -1, will move one pixel to the left of center, and 1 pixel up.  moveByOffset will move from current location by amount of offsets...

I Update my code :                                                                                                           int rectWidth = rectPop.getSize().getWidth();
int rectHeight = rectPop.getSize().getHeight();
    for (int i = 1; i < rectWidth ; i++) {
        actions.moveToElement(rectPop,-rectHeight+i,-1).perform();
        actions.click();
    }

